# Select Last Previous month in Conditional Split Transformation Editor

Tags: ssis, conditional-compilation, sql-date-functions

There is a column called [Month] that I am working on. The goal 
is to dynamically select ONLY the last month (as the data comes
in monthly, but it has old data as well).

In the Conditional Split 
Editor I wrote the following

```
MONTH([Month])=MONTH(DATE())-1 And YEAR([Month])=YEAR(DATE()),
```

but it did not work - red all through.

Is there a better way to write this in the Conditional Split 
Transformation Editor?

Comment: You have data flowing through the pipeline with dates attached. The desire is to filter the data into two segments - previous month and other. Previous month will be any dates that exist in the previous calendar month (as determined by current day). Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need something like this:

```
[month] >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
and [month] < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Eduard Bader. Now I am thinking: Won't it be better to set it up using a variable. That way, if the monthly data does not come in, for any reason, there would be no disruption. Things will continue when data does come in.